# Monitor/spy on tty1 or see the output from tty1 via SSH?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, tty, remote-control

I started an `fsck` locally from tty1 on my Linux server and it seems to take forever. Would I have thought about this before or known I would have run a `screen fsck`.

Is there any way to monitor tty1 via SSH or see the output from the fsck process running? I don't need to interact, just see how it's going.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `tty1` is the first virtual console on a Linux system, you can view its contents *via* `/dev/vcs1`:

```
cat /dev/vcs1
```

(as `root`).

(Thanks to [Sato Katsura](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117516/sato-katsura) for pointing out that this is Linux-specific!)